# Existence of meromorphic function implies biholomorphic map onto the sphere.

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

Let $M$ be a closed simply connected Riemann surface, and let $f: M \to \overline{\mathbb C}$ be a meromorphic map with a simple pole in a point $p \in M$. Is it true that $f$ is injective? That $f$ is surjective?

Also, one should not use the uniformization for Riemann surfaces to prove it. Surjectivity should follow from injectivity.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you mean $f$ has only one pole and this pole is simple. Am I right?

Comment: You don't even need to assume $M$ is simply connected :) If $f$ has precisely one simple pole, then $f$ is a bijective holomorphic map from $M$ to $\overline{\mathbb C} = \mathbb CP^1$, and so $M\cong \mathbb CP^1$.

Comment: @Landscape, yes, you are right.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin: my question was the reason for that... why is it injective / surjective? Maybe I am missing something trivial...

Comment: It's surjective because otherwise, you may assume that $f(M)\subset\mathbb C $, and since $M$ is compact, maximum modulus principle implies that $f$ must be constant, a contradiction. To show it's injective, you may show that the number of pre-images(counting multiplicity for critical points) of each point in $\bar{\mathbb C}$ under $f$ is constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $M$ is a closed surface, every holomorphic function on it has as many zeros as poles (counting multiplicities), by the argument principle. Justification:

1. $M$ can be covered by finitely many patches $U_j$ biholomorphic to domains in $\mathbb C$
2. You can write $M$ as a finite union $\bigcup \overline{V_k}$ where the domains $V_k$ are disjoint, each $V_k$ is  contained in some $U_j$, each boundary $\partial V_k$ is piecewise smooth and does not contain the zeroes or poles of $f$.
3. The argument principle, applied to $V_k$, gives the difference between the numbers of zeroes and poles of $f$ in $V_k$ as $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial V_k} (f'/f)$
4. Summing the integrals in 3 over $k$, we get zero because each part of $\partial V_k$ is traveled twice, in opposite directions.

Therefore, for every $w\in\mathbb C$ the function $f-w_0$ has precisely one zero in $M$.

Comment: let $M$ be the open unit disk, it has no boundary. The function $z \mapsto 1/z$ has one simple pole in $0$ but has no zero in the disk. Which version of the argument principle are you using?

Comment: @Second I meant "is a closed surface". Answer corrected and expanded now.